# What is the difference between two methods of addressing field using rvest

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I have quick question about `rvest`. 
What is the difference between these 2 calls?

```
library(rvest)
document <- read_html('http://www.wikidata.org')
```

#### Chained XPath

```
content <- document %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]")

string <- document %>% 
    html_node(xpath = "//div[3]/div/div/div") %>% 
    html_text()

> string

# [1] "\n\n\n\n\nWelcome to Wikidata\nthe free knowledge base with
# 25,268,822 data items that anyone can edit\nIntroduction
```

#### Whole XPath

```
string<- document %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div") %>% 
    html_text()

> string
# [1] "   Learn about data"
```

They return different results while I think they should return the same.

This first one is wrong. I've check this via firebug on that page the XPATH is:

```
"/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div"
```

Why does it seek outside the node I filtered upon?

Is it my wrong understanding only or some page issue or some library bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html_nodes` help page actually speaks about this:

> XPath selectors ---------------------------------------------
>   chaining with XPath is a little trickier - you may need to vary
>   the prefix you're using - // always selects from the root noot
>   regardless of where you currently are in the doc

So if you use `//` after a pipe the search will disregard where it was and find any `div/span[3]` in the tree.

You want to use:

```
content <- document %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]")

string <- content %>% 
    html_node(xpath = "div[3]/div/div/div") %>% 
    html_text()
```

Without the initial `//` after the 'filter'.

This is the same as

```
string<- document %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div") %>% 
    html_text()
```

Comment: ok. so tell me in my example variables `scr` and `cn` have the same information? They are my 'document'. I thought using `cn <- scr %>% html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[6]")` I've limited this second to have less nodes than `scr`?

Comment: You have, if you don't use `//` in the xpath, edited trying to be clearer

Comment: Aha! I'm stupid! I've written `heaBM <- cn %>% html_node(xpath = "/div/span[3]") %>% html_text()` with one `/` and got empty string. Great! Small oversight caused my issue. Thanks a lot!